# Re-assembling split filenames with python

Tags: python, parsing

I tried figuring this out with Powershell; but couldn't quite get there. Could someone please help me out with doing this in standard Python?

I'm having trouble re-assembling certain filenames (and discarding the rest) from a text file. The filenames are split up (usually on three lines) and there is always a blank line after each filename. I only want to keep filenames that begin with `OPEN` or `FOUR`. An example is:

```
OPEN.492820.EXTR
A.STANDARD.38383
333

FOUR.383838.282.
STAND.848484.NOR
MAL.3939

CLOSE.3480384.ST
ANDARD.39393939.
838383
```

The output I'd like (in a text file) would be:

```
OPEN.492820.EXTRA.STANDARD.38383333
FOUR.383838.282.STAND.848484.NORMAL.3939
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: searching for 'open' or 'four' , the concatenating of the subsequent lines (until reaching a blank line) isn't working out so well for me, right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
build = []
for line in open('xxx.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line:
        build.append(line)
    else:
        if build[0][:4] in ('OPEN','FOUR'):
            print( ''.join(build), file=outfile )
        build = []
```

Comment: Thank you, that's getting me closer `OPEN.492820.EXTRA.STANDARD.38383333FOUR.383838.282.STAND.848484.NORMAL.3939` I'd love to know how to iterate once a blank line is found.

Comment: yikes, `+"\n"` only took me over an hour :), I think i've got what I need now, thank you again.